# Orika clean MapperFactory

Tags: java, spring, orika

I´m using Spring MVC and Orika to mapper some entities into XML, but the problem that I´m facing is that when I try to reuse a MapperFactory with some new mappers in the same instance, not only dont remove the previous mapper that I registered, but after supposedly add the new one, only invoke in the map method call, the first mapper that I register.

Here some code:

```
@Override
public void configureMapper() {
    ConverterFactory converterFactory = factory.getConverterFactory();
    ClassMapBuilder builder = factory.classMap(PublicProcurement.class, RequestForQuotationBody.class)
            .mapNulls(false);
    for (DocumentBodyMapper<RequestForQuotationBody, PublicProcurement> mapper : mappers) {
        mapper.register(builder, converterFactory);
    }
    builder.register();
}

@Override
public void setMappers(List<DocumentBodyMapper<RequestForQuotationBody, PublicProcurement>> documentBodyMappers) {
    this.mappers = documentBodyMappers;
}
```

So first time I configure the MapperFactor a mappers list with {AMapper.class}, then after finish to create that xml, I invoke again passing this time a mappers list {BMapper.class, CMapper.class}. But this time when I invoke the map. Only AMapper.class appear, so only the xml regarding AMapper happens.

Any idea how to reset the MapperFactory?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Since ´m using Spring I define my mapper as prototype and I creating a new instance in every transaction to clean the mapperFactory

Comment: Pay attention to the overhead caused by recreating MapperFactory each time, it's definitely not the right way to use it.

Comment: is the only way that I found to clean the mapperFactory and can reuse it as dynamic multi-mapper. I think Orika was not conceive for what my functionality needs.

Comment: Maybe but I didn't get why do you need to clean it. The classes you want to map to are finite, maybe some fields should/or not be mapped for each request then what you want to use is a dynamic filter. I use Orika to map arbitrary JsonNode I did'nt come cross this particular need to clean the mapper factory. I think I miss your point

Comment: because I have a mapper that reggist a list o mappers, those mappers can change. So imagine my multiMapperClass sometimes can register AMapperClass and BMapperClass, and sometimes CMapperClass and BMapperClass. That´s why I need to clean the MapperFactory of multiMapperClass

Comment: Think of using multiple MapperFactory (for each case) instead of dynamically register/cleaning mappers and if the number of MapperFactory ...

Comment: there´re more than 500 posible combinations XD

Comment: OK :) Anyway I think you have to watch loaded classes in your case, cause Orika generate mappers on the fly this is a costy operation, if you keep Mapper Factory in the prototype scope it may not benefit you instead it can be painful (huge performance impact)

Comment: The performance is good so far my friend. But thanks anyway ;)